# Firebase notification await some time between messages Spring boot

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a chat in my app, so when someone send a message a notification is sent. The problem is that if a user send 10 messages for example the notification will be sent 10 times too.
I wonder if there is a way to send just one message and wait for like 5 minutes until send another one to that same token.
I am using Java Spring boot.
This is my send notification function:

```
public void sendChatNotification(User user){
        if(user.getToken()!=null) {
            try {
                Notification notification = Notification.builder().setTitle("Title").setBody("Body").build();
                Message message = Message.builder().setToken(user.getToken()).setNotification(notification).putData("payload", "logged-home").build();
                firebaseMessaging.send(message);
            } catch (FirebaseMessagingException error) {
                throw new ApiRequestException("Error!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no such configuration parameter for FCM messages. The only parameter is time-to-live. But if the number of unique users is not huge (like < 1G) then it would be easy to implement in Java a kind of cache with key = User and value = lastSendDateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would do it in this way:**

1. collect the messages in the table with `createdAt` field
2. setup a Scheduled Task in Spring Boot at every (30-60 secs) and check if there is not delivered message = `deliveredAt` field is NULL. (and SELECT in `createdAt` ordering)
3. if there are some not sent, send them at once, and fill the `deliveredAt` field

I hope this helped.